# error when insert to varchar column

Tags: mysql

i have following qquery in MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adds` ( 
  `add_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `subcategory` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `district` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `discription` varchar(5000) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `price` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `mobile` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL
)
```

then i try to insert row via following code

```
$insert = mysql_query("insert into adds(title,email,name,category,subcategory,district,city,discription,price,address,mobile,date) values('$title','$email','$name','$cat','$subcat','$district','$city','$description','$price','$address','$mobile','$date')") or die(mysql_error());
```

now if i give a value to my description field like this=  'lk' :

this is cause to a error.so some one can tell  me why is that?

Comment: add_id is a auto increment value. my problem is for a varchar field if i give value like 'lk ' :    it is cuase to a error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you construct your query, you need to escape the data you are inserting.
You need to at least use addslashes() function in PHP, like this:

```
$insert = mysql_query("insert into adds(title,email) values('".addslashes($title)."','".addslashes($email)."')")
```

However more correct way is to use a different function than addslashes, which properly handles all characters in the data, not only apostrophes.

I am using my custom 'escape' function like this:

```
function escape($text)
{
   return str_replace(array('\\', "\0", "\n", "\r", "'", '"', "\x1a"), array('\\\\', '\\0', '\\n', '\\r', "\\'", '\\"', '\\Z'), $text);
}
```